# trouble proving mod_wsgi is working

Tags: python, apache, wsgi

I've got a problem with getting python WSGI module for Apache on a Debian box up and running, or it could be just me having a hard time proving that it running.

The system is Debian 6.0.6 running python 2.6.6 and Apache 2.2.16  with the mod_python and mod_wsgi enabled; all is a default install without any crazy configurations that I'm aware of as of yet.

What I'm trying to do is have a directory in /var/www/pythontest were a few developers can drop some simple python code and have it executed and display the results in a browser.
(specific reason for this and not just starting with installing Django is that the boss demands it be done this way first, and then I can install Django. go fig.)

I've been trying to follow the Configuration Guide at http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/QuickConfigurationGuide to confirm that everything is working.

The VirtualHost that is setup is

```
>    < VirtualHost ###.##.###.##:80> <br>
>    ServerName test.yyy.com <br>
>
>    LogLevel info  <br>
>    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.test.log <br>
>    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.test.log combined <br>
>
>    DocumentRoot /var/www <br>
>
>    WSGIDaemonProcess yyy.com processes=2 threads=15 display-name=%{GROUP} <br>
>    WSGIProcessGroup yyy.com <br>
>    WSGIScriptAlias /pythontest  /var/www/pythontest/test1.wsgi <br>
>
>    < Directory /var/www/pythontest > <br>
>    Order allow,deny <br>
>    Allow from all <br>
>    < /Directory> <br>
>    < /VirtualHost>
```

and within the pythontest directory is a test1 script from the above listed Configuration Guide.

At this time everything looked to have installed ok without any errors being spat out.
I've been able to read any file/script that I put in the directory, all with 755 permissions. But NONE have executed and displayed the results in the browser.

The error log only contained for the above configuration 
[Fri Dec 28 10:46:21 2012] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=6554): Attach interpreter ''.

At this time all I'm trying to do is get one python wsgi application to run successfully to prove everything is working before making any changes and letting the programmers loose.

I may just be tired and missing the obvious, but any suggestions on what could be the problem and going about proving and resolving it?

Thank you,

Timothy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What URL are you using? The only one which will work with that configuration is /pythontest and it would always execute /var/www/pythontest/test1.wsgi.

If you can access the raw code of any scripts under /pythontest directory of DocumentRoot suggests that VirtualHost isn't even being used.

Possible reasons are that the VirtualHost isn't even enabled and being included by Apache, or it could be because you are using an IP in the VirtualHost name when possibly shouldn't be.

A stuff up on either means it will fall back to default VirtualHost and since you are possibly using same DocumentRoot the default VirtualHost will serve them up as static files.

Answer (score 1):

> The system is Debian 6.0.6 running python 2.6.6 and Apache 2.2.16 with the mod_python and mod_wsgi enabled; all is a default install without any crazy configurations that I'm aware of as of yet.

mod_python fell out of favour years ago.  It's not necessary to run mod_wsgi.  The fact that you have both running on the same server at the same time *is* a crazy configuration.  Unless you need it for another website, I'd strongly recommend removing mod_python.

> specific reason for this and not just starting with installing Django is that the boss demands it be done this way first, and then I can install Django. go fig.

He's right.  Doing it this way means you are certain that it is a problem with your mod_wsgi configuration and nothing to do with Django.  It reduces the number of places you need to look in order to debug something.

Comment: Thank you for info on mod_python.  I have removed it, and am still getting the same results, or lack there of.  Can you point me at any online resources that my clear what is going on?

Comment: Have you read [the debugging techniques](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/DebuggingTechniques) section of the documentation for mod\_wsgi?  Have you posted on [the mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/modwsgi)?